# How to select elements while hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I select elements while I hover them on HTML. Like if I hover a div or its child then I need my control over it. I want to show a border around it. my code is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind('mousemove', function(e) {
        current_id = $(e.target).attr('id');
        jQuery('#'+current_id).css('border','2px solid yellow');        
    });
});
```

But this code will gives me control if I hover a specific div but I need I can show a border even if I am hovering inside a div and same if that div contains a child than on hovering it I can get a border around that child not that parent div.

Comment: show html ro make it more clear

Comment: Why not `$(e.target).css('border','2px solid yellow');` ??

Comment: @undefined because he's probably never heard about `e.target`. put it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `hover` event on all `div` elements. I have created a new class to apply and remove easily the styles applied. You could also add more selectors if you need to apply this style to input elements or span for exemple :

`$('div, span, input').on('hover', ...);`

```
<style>
    .myBorder{
        border : 2px solid yellow;
    }
</style>

$('div').on('hover', 
    function(e) {
        $(this).addClass('myBorder');
    },
    function(e){
        $(this).removeClass('myBorder');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to show a border on any element on the page, you probably can do it without JS, jut with CSS only:

```
*:hover {
    border: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

(for debug purposes it's better to use `outline` instead of `border`)

Comment: thanks it does pretty much what I need, but I want to remove that border from parent when I hover on child!!